# Why is the next pointer near the top of the node?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I was looking into some memory management (`pool` + `malloc` + `free`) implementations using linked list, and I found that in most of them each node is something like this:

```
typedef struct node{
int usedSize;
node* next;
char mem[100];
}
```

and then the `free(ptr)` must be:

```
free(void* ptr){
node* item = (node*)((char*)ptr - sizeof(node*) - sizeof(int));
\\some code to put the "item" back to the pool
}
```

My question is this:
why shouldn't we put the `char mem[100];` in the beginning of the structure to avoid the "pointer manipulation"?

the result is:

```
typedef struct node{
char mem[100]; // moved to the beginning
int usedSize;
node* next;
}
```

and then the `free(ptr)` is simpler:

```
free(void* ptr){
node* item = (node*)((char*)ptr);
\\some code to put "item" back to the pool
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That would work fine if all allocations were exactly 100 bytes. But if the allocations differ in size, how do you find the size of the allocation? Putting the size immediately before the allocation makes it simple.

Comment: thatnks @rici but I don't need to find it, I can access it using
node->usedSize
am I missing something?

Comment: thanks @jxh for answer (3) which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: As I said, you can find it using node->usedSize only if you already know what the size is. But generally, you don't know, because an allocation can be any size. When `free(x)` is called, all you have is the pointer `x`. Now, find the size (unless all allocations are the same size). Perhaps you are thinking that all allocations are the same size *in a single pool* (which might be the case, I suppose). But then every different pool needs a different struct, and consequently different utility functions.

Comment: `((char*)ptr - sizeof(node*) - sizeof(int))` is not guaranteed to do the correct calculation because of struct padding. That should be `(node*)((char*)ptr - offsetof(struct node, mem))`.

Answer (score 1):

1. That pointer manipulation is not particularly complicated. It amounts to a decrement by a compile time constant. As noted in comments, it should actually be:

   ```
   node* item = (node*)((char*)ptr - offsetof(struct node, mem));
   ```
2. Placing that header above the memory allows the memory to be represented by a flexible array member. A flexible array member can only occupy the last position of a structure. This was also noted in comments.

   ```
   typedef struct node {
       int usedSize;
       node* next;
       char mem[];
   } node;
   ```
3. If the size of the memory is large, jumping over the array to reach the next pointer will likely flush data cache lines to load the bookkeeping data. However, a short jump backward from the array will likely access the data already loaded into the cache.